# How to fix an upsert script of a PutDatabaseRecord processor?

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I'm working on an ETL that extracts data from Progress and stores it into PostgreSQL.

[image]

However; when I have duplicate keys, I'm having problems with my upsert.

The problem is that the component is creating an invalid script. As you can see, it is missing the double quotes. It needs to be: `ON CONFLICT ("cdConstrucao")`

[image]

My settings are :

[image]

[image]

Deplayed error :

[image]

Sample table :

[image]

Is there a way to fix it ?

Kind regards
Juliano

Comment: I came across with this issue NIFI-8043: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-8043. They said it was fixed, but I'm having the same problem using the latest release.

Comment: Does it work if you specify the Update Keys property, or if you set Translate Field Names to `true`?

Comment: Unfortunately don’t work @mattyb. I already tried

Comment: I can't reproduce this, what version of NiFi are you using?

Comment: @mattyb 1.16.2, latest one

Comment: @mattyb I can reproduce this.  My columns are snakecase: https://i.imgur.com/vySOPxA.png  `PutDatabaseRecord` is formatting it as `UPPERCASE`, causing error: https://i.imgur.com/X0iSwnH.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are still facing this issue.
Try following 2 settings

```
Statement Type: INSERT_IGNORE, 

Translate Field Names: false
```

Comment: You should format your code, look into markdown documentation with the back tick `